# How to return a data frame cell value as the variable name passed to a function

Tags: python, pandas, function, image-processing, multidimensional-array

I made a function that returns a few statistics, but I would like the last column to be the name of the parameter that is inserted into the function.

The code below shows the function and I would like the last column "Region" to give the value of the parameter that I used to initiate the function "NameofRegion"

```
def roiStats(roi):
    data = {'Mean': np.mean(roi),
            'Median': np.median(roi),
            'StdDev': np.std(roi),
            'Min': np.min(roi),
            'Max': np.max(roi),
            'Region': NameofRegion}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0])
    return df

roiStats(NameofRegion)
```

I would think the answer is:

... `"Region": roi`

But that returns an error: "Must be 1 dimensional".  So the biggest issue is that 'NameofRegion' is a cropped area of an image; A 2d array of pixel values.

Comment: So, it is not really easy to do that, I would recommend to you instead of creating a bunch of variables for the regions, create a dictionary with key the name of the region and value this array, then you can just use the keys of the dictionary to print as you want.

Comment: @BrunoMello Ah, thank you.  That makes sense, I will give that a try.  Question: will the roiStats function work the same on a dictionary?  I just enter the dictionary key in the variable name?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have regions a, b, c, d. Instead of doing something like:

```
roia = #something a
roib = #something b
roic = #something c
roid = #something d
```

Consider doing:

```
roi_dict = {
'a': #something a, 
'b': #something b,
'c': #something c,
'd': #something d
}
```

Then you can do like this:

```
def roiStats("NameOfRegion", roi_dict):
    roi = roi_dict["NameOfRegion"]
    data = {'Mean': np.mean(roi),
            'Median': np.median(roi),
            'StdDev': np.std(roi),
            'Min': np.min(roi),
            'Max': np.max(roi),
            'Region': "NameofRegion"}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0])
    return df

roiStats("NameofRegion", roi_dict)
```

Note that now NameofRegion will be a string and thus you can print it

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  That works, but is similar to my first solution in which I just made two functions: one for roi1 and one for roi2 (i only have 2 roi's so not that tedious).  Unless I am wrong, I will have to initiate the function twice to get the stats and dataframes for roi1 and roi2.

Comment: Yes, that's it. You could, if you had more roi's, put a for-loop to run in the entire dictionary and thus don't have to repeat the function all the time but since it is just 2 I would go for just writing 2 times.

Comment: yeah it does, thank you!  I upcoted you, but I have below 15 clout so it doesnt count it.  Thanks again

Comment: No problem, consider accepting the answer so the question can be considered ended